# ctypes passing C string to Python, ValueError: invalid string pointer

Tags: python, c++, string, ctypes

I'm trying to pass const char * from my C code to Python via ctypes.
Here is my code:

.h file:

```
extern "C" {
    _declspec(dllexport)
        const char * return_string();
}
```

.cpp file:

```
const char * return_string() {
    const char* test = "test";
    return test;
}
```

Python code:

```
a = lib.return_string();
print("a =",a)

b = c_char_p(a).value
print(b)
```

Result:

```
> a = -1781171860 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\krzys\Desktop\test\PythonTest.py",
> line 23, in <module>
>     b = c_char_p(a).value ValueError: invalid string pointer 0xFFFFFFFF95D5796C [Finished in 0.1s]
```

What causes this problem?

Is it related to some memory management or just it is wrong approach of getting C string?

Comment: **C is not C++ is not C!**

Comment: Yup, corrected. My mistake :)

Comment: You posted basically a toy C++ implementation of `return_string`.  I bet that your real implementation will eventually do something more substantial than return a string literal.  If that's the case, the function is dangerous in that it may wind up returning a pointer to a local variable, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: In that case is there a way to pass that value properly? I've read some other articles and topics, where exactly this approach used to work fine.

Comment: The default return type is a C int, so it's truncating the pointer value to 0x95D5796C, which then gets sign extended to the the invalid address 0xFFFFFFFF95D5796C. You need to set `lib.return_string.restype = c_char_p`. Please read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: Yes, setting restype to c_char_p for this method solved the problem. Thank you very much for help.